# entity framework 6 generate extra join when send query to sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my framework that develop by entityframework 6:

User DataModel :

```
[DataContract]
[Table("SEC_User")]
public class UserDataModel : EntityBase
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("UserID")]
    public int UserID{get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    [Column("UserName")]
    public string UserName{get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    [Column("UserKindRef")]
    public int UserKindRef{get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
}
[DataContract]
[Table("SEC_User_View")]
public class UserViewDataModel : UserDataModel
{
    [DataMember]
    [Column("UserKindTitle")]
    public string UserKindTitle{get;set;}        
}
```

DataAccess Method:

```
public UserViewDataModel GetByUserName(string userName)
    {
       using (Context)
       {
        return (from entity in Context.EntityList
                 where entity.UserName == userName
                 select entity).FirstOrDefault().ToEntity();
       }
    }
```

Sql Profiler :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
[Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Limit1].[UserKindRef] AS [UserKindRef], 
[Limit1].[UserKindTitle] AS [UserKindTitle]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[UserKindTitle] AS [UserKindTitle], 
    [Extent2].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    [Extent2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Extent2].[UserKindRef] AS [UserKindRef], 
    ''0X0X'' AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[SEC_User_View] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SEC_User] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserKey] =[Extent2].[UserKey]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[UserName] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent2].[UserName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'admin'
```

Unfortunately when UserViweDataModel Inherited from UserDataModel entityframework , entityframework use select to select and join SEC_User_View to SEC_User and it's wrong.
It should be like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[UserKindRef] AS [UserKindRef], 
[Extent1].[UserKindTitle] AS [UserKindTitle]
FROM [dbo].[SEC_User_View] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[UserName] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[UserName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'admin'
```

what's my mistake????

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why do you need to inherit?  both classes have a table and unique properties here so EF has no idea All are in 'SEC_User_View'   Why do you need the base class like this?  Just put all the properties in 'SEC_User_View'

Comment: @EricKelly:  at the first, It's my standard framework and do it on all project. Another point entityframework use first table on view for primary and do save changes on first table(I hope I understand correctly), but some times first table is not primary. I have to separate tablemodel and viewmodel . tablemodel for save changes and viewmodel for selection. also some times for performance not necessery use view for select list ...

Answer (score 0):

`Table(SEC_User)` and `Table(SEC_User_View)`. You *told* EF you wanted two tables.

[Inheritance with EF: Table Per Hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

The default for EF is TPH, but – by decorating both classes with `Table` – you told it you want TPT (see part 2 of the blog article I posted above).

BTW, if you do want TPH – which it sounds like you do – the one and only table is going to be the base class, not the derived.